# How can I stop my manager from trying to sabotage my transfer by spreading rumours?

Tags: software-industry, career-development, human-resources, unprofessional-behavior

I am facing a difficult situation at work.

I started at my current company four years ago asa a junior developer. Today I am an unofficial manager, delegating work and possessing the most technical knowledge in my team. I got additional responsibilities thanks to hard work and countless hours studying and educating myself. However, three years of negotiations only got me the official title of Software Engineer.

I recently realised that my manager has no interest in my career development.
I wanted to be transferred to another team, and his initial declining escalated into a conversation that involved senior management and the CIO.

The other team collaborated with me in the past and would be happy to have me. However, escalating tensions with my current manager led to a fallout which ultimately involved HR.

My manager ultimately was pressured into agreeing to the transfer, but we still 
have work together for two months. He is now spreading rumours about me.

I don't want anyone to mischaracterise my behaviour or decisions. I have email proof that my manager is spreading rumours and the last thing I want to do is get him fired. However, I do not want to be bullied in the next two months.

My question is: **how could I tell my boss he can't bully me without causing conflicts that can prevent me from reaching my work objectives?**

Comment: You did sort of complain to HR.  However, you were justified in your complaints, confused why that rumor (which is the truth) is a bad thing.  Your leaving the team.  What is your question?

Comment: in which country is this?

Comment: This is in the United States. You guys are right, it is NOT a rumor. It is the truth and my manager just needs to be coached as to what is appropriate behavior in a US company. He has only been in US for a short period of time and I don't think he understands the corporate culture here compared to his home country.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you have dealt with the situation already. You have a replacement job lined up and every reason to believe that things will work out in the long run.

The best bet is to keep doing your job and ignore the manager whenever he acts inappropriately (do whatever is most professional).

Answer (score 2):

> He also tells me I am there for 2 more months and he proceeds to intimidate me and starting the conversation about going to his party again

I would sit it out and smile in his face. Yes, you are there for two more months *only*, in which he has to replace you. You can cooperate fully in that with all your knowledge or not and let him do the planning of the handover (he seems to like to be in control, so he may be stupid enough to accept that), and everything which he doesn't explicitly ask for is not getting done. Ask a rather often by email or in the team meeting (not unprofessionally often) how to handle things to document the handover and you willingness to collaborate fully. The stress of handling the situation may even cause more outbreaks of him via email and/or with others present to let himself underline his unprofessional behavior. Log every really unprofessional outbreak which happens via email or in front of the team. When a few accumulate, report to HR. Give HR a very specific summary like use of swearwords, threatening behavior, repeated private invitations despite declining.

Then go and don't look back. Or in this case you can look back, and after some time the manager may be gone.